# Going from console to win32 applications

Tags: c, winapi, visual-studio-2013, console

After some time coding in c in a simple console, I decided I wanted to try and code an actual Win32 application. However, upon selecting the option, the sheer amount of unknown code that surfaced on my IDE (Visual Studio 2013) just to open a blank window was overwhelming, as I don't understand half of it's meaning or even what to do, since, even simple printf commands yield no result... Can someone point me to a way to understand the differences between console and application? Or at least someway I can insert my current coding knowledge in an application environment?

Comment: What kind of application are you looking to write? A GUI app? A DirectX graphics or game app?

Comment: [Petzold](http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Windows%C2%AE-Edition-Developer-Reference/dp/157231995X) is the definitive book for learning Windows programming. However this sort of question is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn Not quite sure... It's supposed to be for a kind of game, a strategy style of game, but even though it requires a lot of "part" selecting from the user (which might make it more of a GUI, at heart), it would eventually be used to run an actual game... Like a card game if you will - selecting cards requires input, playing them wouldn't, at this stage... Does it help? Sorry if it's confusing, it's still hard to explain, not used to graphical stuff yet...

Comment: @jonathan Potter i'm talking about programming in general , i'm sorry if it is off-topic , but could you please explain me why is it off-topic here ins tack overflow ?

Comment: From the official StackOverflow off-topic reasons list: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Well so my question wasn't off-topic , in that list i did nothing against the rules , i basically asked for a way to pass through console programming to win 32 applications , since i don't understand the 2nd one

Comment: How about this then? "too broad: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs." We're not saying your question is bad. It's just not very suitable for StackOverflow. SO works best when the question is quite specific. Your question is quite open eneded.

Comment: Understood , i'll take care next time

Comment: Using the win32 API directly is a nightmare. So I suggest you use a GUI toolkit instead that supports win32. And here comes the opinionated part: [Qt](http://www.qt.io/) is quite nice. (Oh, I just realized that requires you to use [tag:c++] instead of [tag:c] ... well, for a GUI application, you could consider switching the language ... or have a look at [GTK](http://www.gtk.org/))

Comment: Adding to that comment: Using a decent GUI toolkit not only saves you from the really nasty innards of the win32 API, it also ensures your code stays portable on different platforms.

Comment: @FelixPalmen Thank you , appreciated , i will discover more about it ^^

Comment: Again adding some info: GUI abstractions are a typical usecase for *OOP* (object oriented programming) ... a window is an object, a button is an object, a menu is an object composed of menu-item objects ... That's the reason you will find a LOT more GUI toolkits for [tag:c++] than for [tag:c]. [GTK](http://www.gtk.org/) goes the special way of using *OOP* with [tag:c] syntax (It's possible after all). "raw" win32 API is strictly procedural and would probably cause you to go crazy as soon as your application gets bigger :)

Comment: Right , i understand , so your advice to me is i should keep learning until the end C then going for c++ to reach what i want right ?

Comment: Uhm, no, there's no "end". My advice is: A lot of ppl identified GUIs to be a perfect example for object-oriented programming. So if you want to try it, *either* use a language with builtin OOP features (like e.g. [tag:c++]) *or* be prepared to do some OOP in [tag:c]. Either way, use a decent GUI toolkit, it will help you a lot. (the only answer here suggests SDL which is the perfect choice if you intend to create a game or multimedia app)

Answer (score 3):

Working with the Windows API can be quite the experience for a newcomer. The act of opening a window does, certainly, involve a lot of boilerplate code. The good news is a lot of that boilerplate rarely changes, and when it does it'll be for very special circumstances that you can go research. That's why Visual Studio spits the whole mess out for you by default.

There are plenty of resources to learn with, including Microsoft itself: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384843.aspx

To help situate you, understand that a lot of what you're looking at that's probably confusing are typedefs used on primitive types. This helps maintain backwards compatibility with programs created for older versions of Windows, and adds semantic meanings to types. A lot of the preprocessor stuff you see in header files is actually conditional compilation - it's checking what environment you're compiling in, what version of Windows, etc. and then providing the correct typedefs so that what actually compiles works on the desired Windows platform. Stuff that's greyed out in VS2013 is stuff that Intellisense sees isn't going to be compiled based on the current #defines and a lot of it may be relatively ancient. A big part of the Windows API for a long time was a strong desire to not break backwards compatibility. This was a huge advantage for Windows, because it means my program you wrote for Windows 3.1 isn't going to be hosed by Windows 95 rolling out. Or XP, 2000, Vista, 7, 8, 10, etc. It does mean a lot of stuff makes it into the API and stays there.

They try to hide a lot of that in the headers, but you'll also see deprecated input variables to functions and the like (this parameter should always be NULL...etc), and you just have to read the documentation. Thank the internet.

For example, an LPCSTR is just a const char*, but the LPCSTR signifies that it's a null-terminated constant string. In fact, you may see that's it's not a const char*, but a CONST CHAR* where CONST and CHAR are #defines themselves to make sure the correct keywords and types are used. In your case it'll probably end up being just normal const char*.

My suggestion, rather than diving into about as complicated a C-API as possible, is to look at something like SDL. SDL is a much simpler C API designed to provide an interface to the operating system's windowing, graphics, and input, while hiding the dirty details of the API, be it Windows, Mac, or Linux. https://www.libsdl.org/

It uses openGL for its graphics. If you're making any kind of game you'll be using some kind of graphics API to talk to the video card. The native Windows graphics API is DirectX, but openGL is the very commonly used cross-platform API. Both APIs allow you to make use of a computer's video hardware to render graphics.

Edit: I'll add, since I went off and voiced an opinion on libraries, which is why these types of questions are probably frowned upon, that I think it's fair to say that SDL is the de facto standard for C third-party multimedia libraries. Also commonly mentioned is SFML, which provides much the same functionality but is more object-oriented and written in C++.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation , you desearve an upvote , but i can't :P , yet it was very easy to understand , you have some more tips to start through it ?

Comment: Since you have VS 2013 (hopefully the Community or Pro+ edition rather than the Express edition), you can also make use of [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK) and the [Direct3D Win32 Game template](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2015/01/06/direct3d-win32-game-visual-studio-template.aspx) which are used by the [tutorials](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started)

Comment: That's a good answer, I just would add that SDL focuses on games and multimedia and depending on what you actually want to create, another library (like e.g. GTK, or if switching to [tag:c++] is not an issue: Qt) might be better suited.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio, when you create a win32 app project, click on next, and click on empty project. This will eliminate all the stuff that Visual Studio creates for a win32 app, but then you start with no files. You'll probably want to start with some simple example C program for windows from a book or web site.